# Linux shell: Changing decimal (float) separator from dot to comma

Tags: linux, bash, shell, floating-point

This is an **output example** I get in some programs:

```
$ reportspeed
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.4 kH/s
```

And this another example:

```
$ reportspeed
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.43 kH/s
```

As long as, in both cases it is obvious that those one or two **numbers behind the `.` dot** is the decimal part, I would like to change that output to:

```
$ reportspeed | decimalcomma
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,4 kH/s
$ reportspeed | decimalcomma
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,43 kH/s
```

This is: using **comma `,` instead of `.`** if there are one or two decimal characters behind it.
This supposes that, when some program uses `.` **dots for thousands** separator, it will not be changed, like in:

```
$ anotherprogram
Speed.Other.Thing....:   33.112 H/s
$ anotherprogram | decimalcomma
Speed.Other.Thing....:   33.112 H/s
```

I think this can be done by using sed, awk, perl or maybe even shell expansion, but I am not very experienced on it.

Could someone give me some help, please?

EDIT-1: Even when this question requests solutions for "one or two numbers behind the dot" as a method to distinguish between comma for thousands, for those arriving here interested in not such limitation (and as long as the title could suggests it does not exist), here is the method firstly proposed by @almas shaikh (thanks you, boy):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -r 's/\.([0-9]{1,2})\b/,\1/g'
```

**Testing:**

```
cat file
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.4 kH/s
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.43 kH/s
Speed.Other.Thing....:   33.112 H/s

sed -r 's/\.([0-9]{1,2})\b/,\1/g' f
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,4 kH/s
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,43 kH/s
Speed.Other.Thing....:   33.112 H/s
```

**PS:** On OSX use:

```
sed -E 's/\.([0-9]{1,2})[[:>:]]/,\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$ echo "Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.4 kH/s" |sed 's/\.\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\b/,\1/g'
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,4 kH/s
$ echo "Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.44 kH/s" |sed 's/\.\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\b/,\1/g'
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254,44 kH/s
$ echo "Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.444 kH/s" |sed 's/\.\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\b/,\1/g'
Speed.GPU.#*...:   254.444 kH/s
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is impossible. How is the poor program supposed to know whether a number like `33.112` is European notation for "thirty-three thousand one hundred and twelve" or Anglophone notation for "thirty-three point one one two"?

Comment: I am not asking at all for a program capable of distinguish what does some `.` or `,` mean. I just want a method (alias, script, command) that helps «using [changing] comma `,` instead of `.` if there are one or two decimal characters behind it» in order to implement it in my programs for some data outputing.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that none of those "some programs" outputs three decimal places? Do you have the source code for them? If not, you are treading on very thin ice.

Comment: Obviously. They are "my programs", as told. Anyway, anyone using the answers on this thread for their own purposes must make sure of the three decimal places rule you say, by the way. But still, what the original question asks is far to be considered as "impossible".

Comment: Oh, good grief! If they are "your programs" (which you did _not_ tell us), why don't you just output the values in the format that you want?

Comment: Just to avoid making original question too long. Maybe we are not using the same sense for "my programs". They are not programs created by me, but they are under my control (I know how they behave). For example, this thread has been opened for a wrapper I am developing for OCL HashCat (open source, so, yes, source code is available) http://www.hashcat.net . Note the screenshot: `Speed.GPU.#1` has one float after the `.` dot.

Comment: Nothing in the original question requests code valid for "any existing program in the world that outputs floating point numbers in any format". The particular «cases» are clear: those who yield «one or two numbers behind the `.` dot». And, as long as there are many programs that behave exactly in this manner when showing floats, the answer could be useful for other people arriving here during their quests.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]{1,2}\)/\1,\2/g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Failing when there are more than 2 decimal characters after `.`, like in `Speed.Other.Thing....:   33.112 H/s`.

Comment: I didn't get it? when i run `echo "almas.shaikh.... 2.34 3.2222" | above command` i get `almas.shaikh.... 2,34 3,2222` which i think is correct?

Comment: Original Post proposal: «using comma `,` instead of `.` if there are one or two decimal characters behind it». The number thirty thousands could be written `30000` or `30.000`, but `300.00` will never be thirty thousands, so we can be sure that this dot `.` is a float separator and change it by `,`. Sorry for the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Hope above helps now it will check for either one or two digits after decimal point.